# Debian Jessie dist-upgrade failed

Tags: linux, debian, apt-get

I got an error while doing dist-upgrade in Debian 7 to Upgrade to Debian 8. 
It aborted, and I issued the same command again to do a restart. Now I get the following errors:

```
libapache2-mod-fastcgi : Depends on: apache2.2-common (>= 2.2.4) but should not be installed
libapache2-mod-perl2 : Depends on: apache2.2-common but should not be installed
libapache2-mod-php5 : Depends on: php5-json but should not be installed
libapache2-svn : Depends on: apache2.2-common but should not be installed
php5-cli : Depends on: php5-common (= 5.5.24-1~dotdeb+wheezy.1) but 5.6.7+dfsg-1 should be installed
           Depends on: php5-json but should not be installed
           Empfiehlt: php5-readline but should not be installed
php5-curl : Depends on: phpapi-20121212 but not installable
            Depends on: php5-common (= 5.5.24-1~dotdeb+wheezy.1) but 5.6.7+dfsg-1 should be installed
php5-gd : Depends on: phpapi-20121212 but not installable
          Depends on: php5-common (= 5.5.24-1~dotdeb+wheezy.1) but 5.6.7+dfsg-1 should be installed
php5-imagick : Depends on: php5-common (= 5.5.24-1~dotdeb+wheezy.1) but 5.6.7+dfsg-1 should be installed
php5-imap : Depends on: phpapi-20121212 but not installable
            Depends on: php5-common (= 5.5.24-1~dotdeb+wheezy.1) but 5.6.7+dfsg-1 should be installed
php5-intl : Depends on: phpapi-20121212 but not installable
            Depends on: php5-common (= 5.5.24-1~dotdeb+wheezy.1) but 5.6.7+dfsg-1 should be installed
php5-ldap : Depends on: phpapi-20121212 but not installable
            Depends on: php5-common (= 5.5.24-1~dotdeb+wheezy.1) but 5.6.7+dfsg-1 should be installed
php5-mcrypt : Depends on: phpapi-20121212 but not installable
              Depends on: php5-common (= 5.5.24-1~dotdeb+wheezy.1) but 5.6.7+dfsg-1 should be installed
php5-mysql : Depends on: phpapi-20121212 but not installable
             Depends on: php5-common (= 5.5.24-1~dotdeb+wheezy.1) but 5.6.7+dfsg-1 should be installed
php5-pgsql : Depends on: phpapi-20121212 but not installable
             Depends on: php5-common (= 5.5.24-1~dotdeb+wheezy.1) but 5.6.7+dfsg-1 should be installed
php5-tidy : Depends on: phpapi-20121212 but not installable
            Depends on: php5-common (= 5.5.24-1~dotdeb+wheezy.1) but 5.6.7+dfsg-1 should be installed
php5-xdebug : Depends on: php5-common (= 5.5.24-1~dotdeb+wheezy.1) but 5.6.7+dfsg-1 should be installed
pkg-php-tools : Depends on: php5-json but should not be installed
```

apt-get -f install didn't help either.

what will I have to do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can try to install the packages which "should not be installed" by hand:

```
apt-get install php5-json php5-readline
```